# How i could save a block that i had called it before with block_load?

Tags: 7, blocks, installation

I call a block via a block_load function and i do some changes. What i want to save this block with my changes..

Comment: So, you want to update an existing block and save its state. And all that in a hook_enable function. Could you update the OP is these are true? It's important info. And where does the block you want to change come from? Cheers!

Comment: In my project i have some block changes in a hook_block_info_alter (main-menu, language blocks). Now i want to make a refactor and put that changes in a hook_enable and a hook_update function. I need a really help for that issue :(

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of `hook_block_info_alter()`? Or do you just want to make sure that the changes are always written to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the code in the [`block.module`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/7.x) file I can suggest the following:

1. Leave your code in `hook_block_info_alter` unchanged.
2. From your [`hook_enable`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7.x) hook call the following function to force calling and saving your `hook_block_info_alter` code:

   ```
   _block_rehash();
   ```

Quoting from the [function's documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/_block_rehash/7.x):

> Updates the 'block' DB table with the blocks currently exported by
>   modules.

Hope this does it for you!

Comment: Thanks! I had saw it also but i asked if a better way exists... I told this solution to my team and we will leave it as is :) Thank you again!!

Comment: You're welcome Giannis. Any reason why you didn't want to go with that solution in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Block View Alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7.x) hook or [Block Save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_save/7.x) hook

And a complete [Block hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/7.x) you can find it here.

Comment: I want it to put in a hook_enable function of a module, so i do not think this is what i am looking for :(